# Plugin Eclipse 3.x hide perspective bar and "Quick Access" in my Perspective programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perspective

I created one perspective in my plugin eclipse. I want hide the perspective bar and "Quick Access".

I tried to use this:

```
((WorkbenchWindow)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()).setPerspectiveBarVisible(false);
```

but doesn't work.

Any idea for this and for hide "Quick Access"?

Answer (score 1):

For the perspective bar, in your `org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` do the following:

```
@Override
public void preWindowOpen() {
    IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
    configurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(false);
}
```

As for the "Quick Access", Eclipse 3.x did not have this search field. You probably run an Eclipse 4.x using 3.x layout style (e.g. not e4).

You can try to remove it using CSS. In the plugin.xml where your `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` is declared add the following to the `<product>` declaration:

```
 <property
       name="applicationCSS"
       value="platform:/plugin/PLUGIN_NAME/css/default.css ">
 </property>
```

And your CSS should contain:

```
#SearchField {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm newby about to these topics. I created plugin eclipse not RCP application, so there is not the file WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think you can hide the perspective bar nor the "Quick Access" field from a plugin. Since you run a plugin you shouldn't be able to manipulate the main application at such extends. A plugin adds functionality, not disables features.

Comment: I delete all menu and toolbar item, so I thought that was the same for open perspective.